# Error on using "\rl{}" inside "inline math"

Tags: inline, xepersian, cancel

I use `TeXstudio 2.12.16` and want to write `Farsi` words in `\cancelto{value}{expression}`. So I used `xepersian` package and `\rl`. What I tried is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas} 
\begin{document} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node{$ \cancelto{\rl{value}}{\rl{expression}} $};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But `TeXstudio` shows an error near to `\node{$ \cancelto{\rl{value}}{\rl{expression}} $};`. Also when I replace wrong code with `\node{$ \cancelto{value}{expression} $};`, I see no error. So problem must be relative to the using `\rl{}` inside `inline math`. But I do not know what causes the error and how I can solve the problem. Note I need to use `\rl` for writing `Farsi` words.

Comment: Since the error occurs inside math, you might be able to enter it as `\text{\rl}`.  This requires `amsmath`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you. I changed it to `\node{$ \cancelto{\text{\rl{مقدار نهایی}}}{\text{\rl{گزاره اولیه}}} $};` and it works. Please add an answer, then I can accept it and it may be useful for others.

Comment: I've added an answer, but now that I see the entire replacement code, I wonder whether just removing the `$...$` wouldn't work in this particular situation.  The spaces in the `\node` string aren't significant (since they're in math), so they might need to be removed too.  (I'm not really familiar with how to use nodes in a `tikzpicture`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error occurs inside math, and `\rl` represents a letter in Farsi text, you should be able to enter it as `\text{rl}`.  This requires the use of `amsmath`; actually, only `amstext` is required, but since that is loaded automatically by `amsmath` (whose use is very common), there's no need to load it separately.

The OP reports that changing the input to

```
\node{$ \cancelto{\text{\rl{مقدار نهایی}}}{\text{\rl{گزاره اولیه}}} $}
```

works.